# How to find value_type for dereferencing iterator wrapper?

Tags: c++, decltype

I am trying to define the `value_type` of an iterator wrapper that dereferences the `value_type` of the wrapped iterator.

For iterators with a `value_type` that is an actual pointer this is trivial, but I need it to work for some "pointer-like" classes as well. In that case, the `value_type` should be the type returned by the wrapped iterator's `value_type`'s operator->, sans pointer.

Here's a snippet of the current code, which works fine, but...

```
template <typename T>
struct remove_pointer {
    typedef typename remove_pointer<decltype(((T*)0)->operator->())>::type type;
};
template <typename T>
struct remove_pointer<T*> {
    typedef T type;
};
```

and

```
template <typename T_it>
class deref_iterator {
    typedef typename remove_pointer<
                         typename std::iterator_traits<T_it>::value_type
                     >::type value_type;
};
```

This works fine, but I really don't like the `decltype(((T*)0)->operator->())` to get the return type of `T`'s `operator->`.

Is there some nicer method to accomplish this?

Comment: You need `std::declval`. Perhaps `decltype(*std::declval<T>())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your current code is very nearly fine. If I were writing this, I'd use `declval` rather than `(T*)0`, and I'd use the dereference operator rather than `operator->`:

```
template <typename T>
using pointed_to_type_t =
    typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>::type;

template <typename T_it>
class deref_iterator {
    typedef pointed_to_type_t<
        typename std::iterator_traits<T_it>::value_type> value_type;
};
```

Comment: std::declval, very nice! Unfortunately `decltype(*std::declval<T>())` returns a reference, so I was using `operator->` since I already had code to remove the pointer. Or is there some other way to get rid of the reference?

Comment: @zennehoy: Use `std::remove_reference`. Edited.

Comment: I changed the name from `remove_pointer`, as it conflicts with `std::remove_pointer` but has different semantics.

Comment: The point to using `operator->` would be that the object returned by `operator*` might be a proxy.